# What are the patterns in these two matrices?

Tags: visual, pattern, progressive-matrix

I found these puzzles on https://iqmentor.io, and could not figure out the solutions to them. Any thoughts?

I also posted this on Reddit. Including the link here in case you'd like to see more people's attempts:
https://www.reddit.com/r/cognitiveTesting/comments/11b8tiq/iqmentorio_what_are_the_patterns_in_these_3/
(In the Reddit post there was a third puzzle, which someone already posted a satisfactory solution to, so I did not include it here.)

**1.**
[image]
This seems somewhat similar to another problem whose solution is described in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZUr0JYe7zg&t=21s&ab_channel=Puzzles%26Solutions), (and in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kpImPmZ-a9A&ab_channel=Puzzles%26Solutions) with visuals).
My thoughts:

> Best I can come up with is that it's a topleft-botright diagonal sequence, with at most one of the corners moving sides across the horizontal bar, which would yield option 4 as the only answer, but that seems too weak of a pattern compared to the pattern of the puzzle in the video.
>  (Also, that pattern does not completely hold, because in cells 3-4-7, between 3-4 the white square moves to the top-left and is obscured by the black square, but then after the black square moves between 4-7, we should now see the white square in the top-left but we do not.)

**2.**
[image]
This seems like it should be similar to problem #35 in [this video](https://youtu.be/iEWp_83UUXw?t=916).

After putting the below together I realized I made an error, which I retroactively highlighted below, but including it anyway in case it inspires any ideas.

> To get row 3, identify similarities between the items in both diagonals and combine the results. (Expressed using boolean logic, AND the lines in the pictures across the diagonals in rows 1 and 2, and OR the two results to get row 3.)
>
>  Here is a visualization for how this yields cell 8, how I mistakenly thought it yields cell 7, and what it would yield in cell 9:
>  [image]
>
>
>  * There are three pairs of cells across each diagonal: topright-botleft diagonal pairs cells 1-6-8, 2-4-9, 3-5-7; topleft-botright diagonal pairs cells 1-4-9, 2-5-7, 3-4-8. Bottom row is arrived at by combining the results of similarities between the cells in rows 1 and 2 of its two diagonals.
>
>  * For cell 9 this logic would yield the same shape that is in cell 1, and that is not one of the choices.